# Put contents of PHP while loop code within a DIV

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

So I want to apply this DIV class to these PHP items.
This is what I have, I know it does not work, but what would be correct for what I am trying to achieve.

I cant add the class to each individually, as I want the entire contents to be within the one div.

Hope that makes sense, thanks!

```
<?php 

while($campaigns= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    <div class="feeditem">;
    echo "<div class='field'>".$test['part0']."</div>";
    echo "<div class='field'>".$test['part1']."</div>";
    echo "<div class='field'>".$test['part2']."</div>";
    echo "<div class='field'>".$test['part3']."</div>";
    echo "<div class='field'>".$test['part4']."</div>";
    echo "<div class='field'>".$test['part5']."</div>";
    echo "<div class='field'>".$test['part6']."</div>";
    </div>;
}

?>
```

Comment: Put the ```<div class='feeditem'>``` outside the while (the closing div too after the end of the while)

Comment: Do you either need to move the `.feeditem` opening/closing divs outside of your PHP code, or `echo` that line like you're `echo`ing the others, depending on how you want this structured

Comment: @SloanThrasher, so like this...                                                                      
    <?php 
    <div class="feeditem">;
     while($campaigns= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part0']."</div>";
    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part1']."</div>";
    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part2']."</div>";
    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part5']."</div>";
    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part6']."</div>";

    }

    </div>;
    ?>

Comment: Don't put code in a comment. It's unreadable. Edit your question and add it to the end. If I read it correctly, it looks about right.

Comment: What is _$test_ & _$campaigns_ ?

Comment: Hossam, all I am asking is where to put the div. Sloan, that did not work!

Answer (score 0):

You should use an IDE that gives you errors for syntax problems... You do not have all the html code wrapped in `echo "";` statements.

```
while ($campaigns = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<div class="feeditem">';
        echo "<div class='field'>" . $test['part0'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div class='field'>" . $test['part1'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div class='field'>" . $test['part2'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div class='field'>" . $test['part3'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div class='field'>" . $test['part4'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div class='field'>" . $test['part5'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div class='field'>" . $test['part6'] . "</div>";
        echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're trying to accomplish:

```
<?php
echo '<div class="feeditem">';
while($campaigns = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part0']."</div>";
    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part1']."</div>";
    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part2']."</div>";
    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part3']."</div>";
    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part4']."</div>";
    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part5']."</div>";
    echo"<div class='field'>".$test['part6']."</div>";
}
echo '</div>';
```